# which one is faster - string + or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know which one works faster

```
var td = "<td>"+getText()+"</td>";
var tr = "<tr>"+td+"</tr>";
```

vs

```
var td=$('<td/>');
td.append(getText());
var tr = $('<tr/>');
tr.append(td);
```

thanks inadvance

Comment: why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: the first one, as it doesn't rely on accessing the DOM, or downloading the jquery library

Comment: `->` http://jsperf.com/

Comment: If you load jQuery only for this functionality, the '+ way' by far.

Comment: This sounds a little like over optimization...

Comment: You're comparing apples with oranges...

Comment: Those snippets don't even do the same. The first one composes plain strings and the second one composes jQuery objects that encapsulate DOM nodes. It's like asking what's faster: drawing in a notebook or printing a 10-metre vinyl banner.

Answer (score 3):

The first on is faster because it is simple string concatenation. However, the second one is doing completely different job. It actually constructs DOM elements, which you can use. The first one only provides a string at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think first one loads fast, because second one requires jquery library and it takes time to load jquery files, but whereas the first one is pure Javascript doesnt require any other libraries

Comment: I don't think that the time it takes to load the libraries is in the scope of this question. It would be safe to assume that most users already have jQuery cached by their browser - so this load time isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, the first one is way faster than using jQuery, since to get the jQuery CDN file and read it and again execute the code is milliseconds slower than the first one. Though the difference isn't much. Unless you're working on a real-time coding project that has to operate without delays and precisely, you can employ any method.

```
var td = "<td>"+getText()+"</td>";
var tr = "<tr>"+td+"</tr>";
```

So, the above code is "milisecondi-fasto" for me.

Answer (score 0):

Second will work faster then first,

Because Second one will execute just after page load and it will create less string object then first one But in First one ,the string manipulation  will occur and then getText function will call which cause the another function call

Answer (score 0):

If you consider a case of selecting "DOM" elements and performing the operations, then second one is faster.
But on the other side, to work with the jquery it will have to download the "jQuery Library" which makes it slower than simple Java script(i.e.; first one).